# Как изменить скины кнопок на android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Тренируюсь с android на eclipse. Пишу приложение, где кнопки являются картинками. Через какое-то время заменяю все картинки другими с теми же названиями, однако, при запуске эмулятора все равно отображаются старые картинки, хотя их даже в проекте уже нет. Кидаю картинки в папку res/drawable-hdpi, удаляю старые, заменяю при помощи refactor->rename

Comment: это эмулятор, тести на девайсе и не будет таких лагов, я с таким сталкивался.

Comment: а как же другие размеры экранов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй Project->Clean